# Can apples be considered crispy?

Tags: adjectives

So it's common to call an apple crisp, but can you call it crispy? In general at least for me I consider crispy to refer to chips as crisp, as they are dry and brittle, but apples are not. So can an apple be crispy?

Comment: According to [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=crisp+apple%2Ccrispy+apple&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccrisp%20apple%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccrispy%20apple%3B%2Cc0), the string _crispy apple_ is not unknown ... but it _is_ rare. And mainly false positives (crispy apple chips / pie / pudding / turnover; Seneca crispy apples). Dictionary definitions will no doubt appear to sanction it, but they do not address lack of idiomaticity in such loose strings. I'd stick with the idiomatic expression.

Comment: i like my apples crispy ... much better than mushy!

Comment: *Apple crisp* already has a defined meaning.

Comment: I'd say toast is crispy but apples are crisp, the opposite being mushy or mealy. I stopped eating apples until Braeburn came along for that very reason.

Comment: @tchrist but is apple crisp called crisp because of the apple or because of the pastry? In general apple crisp is totally different than a crisp apple.

Comment: This question might receive better answers if it instead asked what the differences are between the adjectives *crisp* and *crispy*. You could then use apples as an example of one area where it may(?) be more appropriate to favor one term over the other.

Comment: Apples are _crunchy_, not crispy.

Comment: We had this discussion last night as we were preparing fajitas for dinner—if I'm asked for "crisp" onion slices, I barely cook them (maybe don't cook them at all), but if I'm asked for "crispy" onions I need to cook (fry) them a lot.

Comment: Crisp wins for apples. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=crunchy+apple%2Ccrisp+apple%2Ccrispy+apple&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccrunchy%20apple%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccrisp%20apple%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccrispy%20apple%3B%2Cc0

Comment: https://www.kfc.com/assets/products/G15022_KFC_14-EC-plate-8-piece-Enviro_0197_RGB-copy-08208607e9e2612a79a43e97953bfede124ab6f523b21952f8ccd7da0f73fe44.jpg Now, *that* is what I call "crispy".

Answer (score -1):

Yes, an apple can be **crispy**.

both crisp and crispy have the same definition when pertaining to food in this dictionary: 'Food that is crispy is pleasantly hard, or has a pleasantly hard surface.'

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/crisp & crispy

for **crisp**:

> 'Whether it's a **crisp** apple, a tender raspberry or a delicious, juicy peach, fresh fruit is a health food that...'
>
> [Sentences with the phrase **crisp apple**](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/sentences-with-the-word/crisp_apple.html)

for **crispy**:

> 'Now there’s a difference – I’ve learned – between crispy and crunchy: granola bars or potato chips are crunchy, because it has crunch all the way through, whereas an apple or a good french-fry is **crispy** because while there is that desired resistance on the outer layer, once you bit in there’s a softer or juicier inside.'
>
> [Crispy Apples & The Crispness Factor for Rosh Hashanah](https://www.shabboshouse.org/crispy-apples-crispness-factor/)

and ' I am munching on this crispy apple.'
[https://forum.wordreference.com/search/3439564/?q=i+am+munching+on+this+crispy+apple&o=relevance&c[node]=3](https://forum.wordreference.com/search/3439564/?q=i+am+munching+on+this+crispy+apple&o=relevance&c%5Bnode%5D=3)

my fav crisp or crispy apple varieties: gala and braeburn.

Comment: So are biscuits crispy? Is a carrot crispy? Please find support for "crispy apples" The Collins dictionary says `Food that is crisp is pleasantly hard, or has a pleasantly hard surface.` It doesn't mention ***crispy***, it has *crisper, crispest, crisps, crisping, crisped* No "crispy"

Comment: The hippo reference doesn't mention "crispy", so how can you say with confidence "Yes, an apple can be crispy"?

Comment: @Mari-LouA, here is collins on crispy:  https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/crispy.  And another: 'I am munching on a crispy apple.' https://forum.wordreference.com/search/3439564/?q=i+am+munching+on+this+crispy+apple&o=relevance&c[node]=3  Collins had sentences for crisp apple but you are right no 'crispy apple' sentences.

Comment: The [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/44563?redirectedFrom=crispness#eid) defines crispness as "The state or quality of being crisp" and the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/44554?redirectedFrom=crispiness#eid) defines crispiness as "The quality of being crispy; crispness".  OED does not mention apples, but it has a citation about the crispiness of the top of a pudding. Thus, because OED says crispness and crispiness can be equivalent, I say crisp and crispy can be equivalent.  And who can argue with an expert opinion from a Jewish cook?

Comment: @ab2 a crispy shalom to you!